# Swift 3 GET request unable to display returned values

Tags: json, cocoa, swift3

Trying to make a GET request with Swift 3 and Xcode8 but not having much luck outputting data I received back from my GET request to the Main.Storyboard either in a label or a text field all I get is all the returned JSON in the console in Xcode8.

There is a snippet of JSON that is returned with my request in Xcode8 which I have attached below for reference. I can access "@encoding" and "@version" but everything else is not able to be accessed and I am not able to figure out why. If this was a web based setup I could just declare a variable and then set it equal to someObject.petfinder[1].shelters etc...

This is my code that is making the request, taking a zipcode from an input field and then building the url and returning it which then is using NSDictionary.

The error I get back in the console is:

"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2017-06-20 12:15:49.392688 PetFinder[47445:9486946] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

```
 // SEND HTTP GET REQUEST

    // DEFINE SERVER SIDE SCRIPT URL
    let scriptUrl = "https://api.petfinder.com/"
    let methodType = "shelter.find"
    let apiKey = "?key=0000000000000000000000000"
    let urlWithParams = scriptUrl + methodType + apiKey + "&location=\(shelterZip)&format=json"


    // CREATE NSURL Object
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: urlWithParams)

    // CREATE URL REQUEST
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl! as URL);

    // REQUEST METHOD - GET / POST
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    // RUN HTTP REQUEST
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error \(error!)")
                return
        }

    // PRINT OUT RESPONSE STRING
    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")


    // CONVERT RECEIVED JSON TO NSDictionary
        do {
            if let convertedJsonIntoDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {

                // Print out dictionary
                print(convertedJsonIntoDict)

                // Get value by key
                let shelterName = convertedJsonIntoDict["shelters"] as? [String: Any]

                for(key, pair) in convertedJsonIntoDict {
                    print("-->\(key) \(pair)")
                }
                print(shelterName!)

            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }

    task.resume()

    }
```

// SNIPPET OF RETURNED JSON FROM THE TOP

```
 {
"@encoding" = "iso-8859-1";
"@version" = "1.0";
petfinder =     {
    "@xmlns:xsi" = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    "@xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation" = "http://api.petfinder.com/schemas/0.9/petfinder.xsd";
    header =         {
        status =             {
            code =                 {
                "$t" = 100;
            };
            message =                 {
            };
        };
        timestamp =             {
            "$t" = "2017-06-20T16:15:49Z";
        };
        version =             {
            "$t" = "0.1";
        };
    };
    lastOffset =         {
        "$t" = 25;
    };
    shelters =         {
        shelter =             (
                            {
                address1 =                     {
                };
                address2 =                     {
                };
                city =                     {
                    "$t" = Nebraska;
                };
                country =                     {
                    "$t" = US;
                };
                email =                     {
                    "$t" = "wooffun@woof.net";
                };
                fax =                     {
                };
                id =                     {
                    "$t" = NE117;
                };
                latitude =                     {
                    "$t" = "13.004";
                };
                longitude =                     {
                    "$t" = "-31.449";
                };
                name =                     {
                    "$t" = WOOF COMPANY;
                };
                phone =                     {
                };
                state =                     {
                    "$t" = NE;
                };
                zip =                     {
                    "$t" = 68001;
                };
            },
```

Comment: Please read the JSON. `shelters` is a key in the dictionary for key `petfinder` rather than the root object. Therefore `shelterName` is `nil` and causes the crash. And the snippet is not JSON, it's the Swift collection type string representation.

Comment: I know it's a key, I am not able to access it's key/pair value. I had tried convertedJsonIntoDict[keyPath: "petfinder.shelters.shelter"] but that does not work either. Thank you for the clarification on what I am seeing in Xcode8 that makes things a bit more clear.

Comment: I also tried self.shelterResult.stringValue = convertedJsonIntoDict["shelters"] which returned "cannot subscript a value of type 'NSDictionary' with an index of type 'String'

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all – and as always

- Do not use `NSDictionary` in Swift. You throw away the type information.
- Do not use Foundation classes like `NSURL`, `NS(Mutable)URLRequest` if there is a native Swift counterpart.
- A GET request does not require an `URLRequest` at all, it's the default.

Second of all lets use a type alias for convenience reasons.

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String:Any]
```

This code is supposed to extract the keys and values you are looking for

```
let scriptUrl = "https://api.petfinder.com/"
let methodType = "shelter.find"
let apiKey = "?key=0000000000000000000000000"
let urlWithParams = scriptUrl + methodType + apiKey + "&location=\(shelterZip)&format=json"

// CREATE NSURL Object
let myUrl = URL(string: urlWithParams)!

// RUN HTTP REQUEST
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myUrl) { data, response, error in

    if error != nil {
        print("error \(error!)")
        return
    }

    // CONVERT RECEIVED JSON TO NSDictionary
    do {
        if let rootDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? JSONDictionary,
            let petfinder = rootDictionary["petfinder"] as? JSONDictionary {

            // Get value by key
            if let shelters = petfinder["shelters"] as? JSONDictionary,
                let shelter = shelters["shelter"] as? [JSONDictionary] {

                for item in shelter {
                    for (key, value) in item {
                        print("-->\(key) \(value)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: Ok I understand. I am still unclear on as to why I am not able to write  self.shelterResult.stringValue = "-->\(shelter["name"])" and have the names of each shelter display in the text field but that is beyond the scope of my original question.